# Minimising the largest max-relatve entropy any quantum state can have with respect to other states drawn from a set

Tags: max-entropy

The max-relative entropy between two states is defined as

$D_{\max}(\rho||\sigma) := -\log \max\{\lambda: \lambda\rho \le \sigma \}$.

Let $\mathcal{R} := \{\rho_k\}$ be a set of $K$ states for a quantum system $Q$. Consider minimising the largest max-relative entropy any quantum state $\sigma$ of $Q$ can have with respect to a state drawn from $\mathcal{R}$, i.e. calculating

$\alpha := \inf_\sigma \left[\max_k \left(2^{D_{\max}(\rho_k||\sigma)}\right)\right]$.

Is it true that the infimum is attained by setting $\sigma$ to a uniform mixture of $\{\rho_k\}$, i.e. $\sigma = \frac{1}{K} \sum_k \rho_k$?